# How is the Service Record ranking calculated?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

After playing 10 games, I was given the Competitive Skill Ranking of Bronze III.  I've seen other players that are lower levels of Bronze and even Silver, Gold, and Onyx rankings.

How is this ranking calculated?  Is there anything special outside of a symbol that players get for being different ranks?